# Is there any better way to optimize code in setting parameters using 'ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter'?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

Actually I'm using JDBCTemplate which can batch insert using `ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter` object.

However, it is very uncomfortable setting parameters in query when it has many parameters.

In my case, actually, it has 44 parameters.
Here is my code.

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query.toString(), batchArgs, listSize,
            new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<DocUsageDTO>() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, DocUsageDTO arg) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setString(1, arg.getClientIp());
                    ps.setInt(2, arg.getClientOs());
                    ps.setString(3, arg.getClientOsVersion());
                    ps.setString(4, arg.getContentCode());
                    ps.setString(5, arg.getContentCreateTime());
                    ps.setString(6, arg.getContentName());
                    ps.setString(7, arg.getCurrentContentName());
                    ps.setString(8, arg.getDeptCode());
                    ps.setString(9, arg.getDeptName());
                    ps.setString(10, arg.getDomainCode());
                    ps.setString(11, arg.getEtc1());
                    ps.setString(12, arg.getEtc2());
                    ps.setString(13, arg.getEtc3());
                    ps.setString(14, arg.getEtc4());
                    ps.setString(15, arg.getEtc5());
                    ps.setString(16, arg.getFileSyncId());
                    ps.setString(17, arg.getFileSyncManagerCode());
                    ps.setString(18, arg.getFileSyncManagerName());
                    ps.setString(19, arg.getFileSyncRevisionNo());
                    ps.setString(20, arg.getFileSyncTagCode());
                    ps.setString(21, arg.getFileSyncTagName());
                    ps.setInt(22, arg.getLocationContext());
                    ps.setString(23, arg.getLogDate());
                    ps.setInt(24, arg.getLogType());
                    ps.setString(25, arg.getOwnerCode());
                    ps.setString(26, arg.getOwnerDeptCode());
                    ps.setString(27, arg.getOwnerDeptName());
                    ps.setString(28, arg.getOwnerName());
                    ps.setString(29, arg.getPositionCode());
                    ps.setString(30, arg.getPositionName());
                    ps.setString(31, arg.getProcessCode());
                    ps.setString(32, arg.getProcessName());
                    ps.setInt(33, arg.getProductType());
                    ps.setInt(34, arg.getPurpose());
                    ps.setInt(35, arg.getPurposeFailReason());
                    ps.setInt(36, arg.getPurposeStatus());
                    ps.setString(37, arg.getSecLevelCode());
                    ps.setString(38, arg.getSecLevelName());
                    ps.setString(39, arg.getUserCode());
                    ps.setString(40, arg.getUserName());
                    ps.setString(41, arg.getWriterCode());
                    ps.setString(42, arg.getWriterDeptCode());
                    ps.setString(43, arg.getWriterDeptName());
                    ps.setString(44, arg.getWriterName());
                }
            });
```

Is there any better way to optimize code in setting parameters using `ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't `ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter`, it's your query having so many parameters that **any** code will look bulky.

You could try `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to provide the parameters in a map, but then you'll be putting those 44 parameters into a map somehow, which will still require probably an equal amount of code.

You could turn your current StatementSetter into a real class (instead of the anonymous one it's now), then it would be at least encapsulated and be out of sight. After all it's just a problem of appearance, there's nothing wrong with the code itself. That would leave your service class looking a lot cleaner, with something like

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query.toString(), batchArgs, listSize, new DocUsageDTOSetter());
```

Actually you don't necessarily need a map for [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource:A-), as it can use a [bean source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.html). However, this requires the parameter names to match the properties. This means that `INSERT INTO FOO(bar, baz) VALUES (?, ?)` becomes `INSERT INTO FOO(bar, baz) VALUES (:myBeanProperty1, :myBeanProperty2)`, and you'll have to wrap each DTO. So you'd be moving (source code) characters to a different place, and adding some extra object creations.

Comment: You mean there is no way to avoid looking cleaner without setting parameters manually. I appreciate!

Comment: @임석호 not really. `JdbcTemplate` doesn't have very sophisticated mechanisms for the parameters. Although if you *really* want to, you could try `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and `BeanPropertySqlSource`. I'll edit the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a named parameter statement instead of manually assigning each parameter like this to improve readability :

```
Connection con=getConnection();
String query="select * from my_table where name=:name or 
docUsageDTO =:docUsageDTO ";
NamedParameterStatement p=new NamedParameterStatement(con, query);
p.setString("name", "bob");
p.setString("docUsageDTO", arg); // this just expects all paramters as string ! Didn't want to copy and edit your lengthy code
ResultSet rs=p.executeQuery();
```

This way perhaps you could create generalized method to set the parameters by passing in the parameter name and the value by looping through or something which could reduce the code.

Otherwise if you want to reduce code but doesn't mind adding a heavy library then using Hibernate could ease your burden .